# $\omega(z)=z+\frac 1 z$ is univalent function?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I need to find if

> $\omega(z)=z+\frac 1 z$

is **univalent** function

**My attempt:**

First, I know that:

$\omega(z)=z+\frac 1 z$

$=(x+\frac{x}{x^2+y^2})+i(y-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2})$

> Now what?

Comment: Using real and imaginary parts isn't a particularly good strategy here. Take $z,w$ with $z + \frac{1}{z} = w + \frac{1}{w}$, and manipulate the equation to get something of the form $\text{stuff} = 0$, where "stuff" exhibits the possible relations between $z$ and $w$.

Comment: It is very famous [Zhukovsky function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joukowsky_transform). It is univalent *in the open punctured disc* or in its complement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *univalent* means *injective*, then no: $\omega(\pm i)=0$.

More generally, it is clear that $\omega(1/z)=\omega(z)$, and it is easy to prove that this is the only possibility.

In general, no rational function of degree $\ge 2$ is injective, by the fundamental theorem of algebra.